# ¿Alguna especificacion para usar "beforeEditCell" o "afterEditCell" dentro de "cellEditProp"?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

Teniendo este código:

```
var cellEditProp = {
  mode: "click",
  blurToSave: true,
  afterSaveCell: function (row, cellName, cellValue) {
   /************************************/ 
  },

  beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, irow, icol) {
    /***********************************/
  },

  afterEditCell: function (row, cellname, value){
    /***********************************/
  }
}

<BootstrapTable data={this.state.datos} cellEdit={cellEditProp}>
```

¿Por qué la funcion afterSaveCell lo hace perfectamente, pero las otras dos no?
Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Hace perfectamente que?¿Que es lo que quieres?¿Que es lo que no hace? ¿Que librerías estás usando? Mas información a la pregunta por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que lo que estás usando es [react-bootstrap-table](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table), revisando su [documentación](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html) sale que `cellEdit` tiene las siguientes propiedades:

> **mode** : String(click/dbclick) (REQUIRED)
>
> To spectify which condition will trigger cell editing.(click or dbclick)
>
> **blurToSave** : Bool
>
> Enable blurToSave will trigger a saving event on cell when mouse blur on the input field. Default is false.
>
> In the default condition, you need to press ENTER to save the cell.
>
> **beforeSaveCell** : Function
>
> Accept a custom callback function, before cell saving, this function will be called.
>
> This callback function taking three arguments: `row`, `cellName` and `cellValue`
>
> It's necessary to return a bool value which whether apply this cell editing.
>
> **afterSaveCell** : Function
>
> Accept a custom callback function, after cell saving, this function will be called.
>
> This callback function taking three arguments: `row`, `cellName` and `cellValue`

No se si te estés basando en un ejemplo de una versión antigua de la librería o pensarías que las funciones de otro atributo funcionen para `cellEdit`, pero sólo te funcionó `afterSaveCell` porque efectivamente es la única función que este atributo acepta. Tanto `beforeEditCell` como `afterEditCell` no son funciones válidas aceptadas por `cellEdit`.

Comment: Efectivamente. Muchas gracias. He añadido una nueva pregunta sobre esto que quizás usted sepa resolver y me serviría de gran ayuda.